# Why does sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription not work without parameters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, transactional-replication

I am just starting to play around with all the cool replication tools to [Programmatically Monitor Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/monitor/programmatically-monitor-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

One of the early finds is [sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelpsubscription-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

When I run it as

```
 sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription
```

I get

> Msg 20587, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription, Line 77 [Batch Start Line 16]
>
> Invalid '@publication_type' value for stored procedure 'sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription'.

According to MS documents it should be valid with a null default

> NULL (default)

If I run it with the Parameter it works fine.

```
sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription  @publication_type = '0'
```

I using it with transactional replication, on a single server (*Reporting Copy*) I have tried and I get the same results on SQL 2017 & 2016.  I am running it against the distribution database

Not sure If I am doing something stupid, if the MS docs are wrong, or what.

Why does sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription not work without parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking the code reveals that :

```
-- validate @publication_type
    --
    if (@publisher_db is NULL or @publication is NULL) 
        and @publication_type is NULL 
    begin
        raiserror(20587, 16, -1, '@publication_type', 'sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription')
        return (1)
    end
```

This means that if `@publication_type` is NULL then it will throw an error which is expected.

Even on 2014, it is throwing same error.

Also, you just need to run with

`sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription  @publication_type = 0` -- for Transactional publication. since the data type is `INT`.